# Change the default padding between formattedText field and button in JDatePicker

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, datepicker

I want to increase the default gap between the formattedTextField and Button in JdatePicker.
I've tried using setMargin(new Insets(0,100,0,0) on the button component but that changes margin of the component inside the button
[Here is an image of what is happening right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s5xM.png)

There is a small Gap between the text field and calendar button of the lower field. I want to introduce the same gap on the top line

I tried `DatePickerButton.setMargin(new Insets(0,100,0,0)` but that did not work

```
JDatePicker myDatePicker = JDateComponentFactory.createJDatePicker();
  myDateButton.setShowYearButtons(true);
  myDateButton.setTextEditable(true);
  myDateButtonComponent = (JComponent) myDateButton;
  myDatePickerTextField = ((JDatePickerImpl)myDateButtonComponent).getJFormattedTextField();
  myDatePickerTextField.setName("date-Picker");
  myDatePickerTextField.setText(EMPTY_STRING);
  myDatePickerTextField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95,20));
  myDatePickerTextField.setEnabled(true);

  ((JDatePickerImpl) myDateButtonComponent).getComponent(1).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(22, 22));
  myDatePickerTextField.setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.PERSIST);
  myDateButton = ((JButton) ((JDatePickerImpl) myDateButton).getComponent(1));
  myDateButton.setText(EMPTY_STRING);
  myDateButton.setOpaque(false);
  myDateButton.setIcon(Icons.calIcon);
  myDateButton.setName("last-published-date-button");
  myDateButton.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: For better help sooner post a valid [mcve] that demonstrates your issue and post an image of how it should look like

Comment: added an image of how it is looking currently@Frakcool

Comment: I see what you mean, please post a valid runnable example, what layout managers are you using?

Comment: for my layout i'm using GridBagLayout, the default datepicker uses springLayout